# Validate nullable complex child with null conditional operator with FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I am writing validation for a complex type with nullable children using null conditional operator `?`. Example below. I have a `BarValidator` which I want to invoke if `Foo.Bar` is set. How can I achieve this, without warning `CS8620 - Argument cannot be used for parameter due to differences in the nullability of reference types.`?

`RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar).SetValidator(new BarValidator())` gives warning as `BarValidator` expects `Bar`, not `Bar?`. One way is obviously to remove the null conditional operator, but I don't want to change my classes to be able to validate. Another is to change to `AbstractValidator<Bar?>`, however I want this validator to be reusable for `Bar`.

Using FluentValidation 11.8.1, in .Net8.

```
public class Foo(Bar? bar)
{
    public Bar? Bar = bar;
}

public class Bar(string value)
{
    public string Value { get; } = value;
}

public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar).SetValidator(new BarValidator());
    }
}

public class BarValidator : AbstractValidator<Bar>
{
    public BarValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(foo => foo.Value).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: [`.When( ... `](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html) didn't work for you?

Comment: No, I tried When(..). I can nullcheck Foo.Bar in predicate, but Foo.Bar is still nullable in the action so cannot use SetValidator().

Comment: `When(foo => foo.Bar != null).SetValidator(foo => new BarValidator());` No?

Comment: That is not the way to use When?

public IConditionBuilder When(Func<T, bool> predicate, Action action)
  => When((x, _) => predicate(x), action);

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html

Comment: RuleFor(foo => foo.Bar)
.SetValidator(new BarValidator())
.When(foo => foo.Bar != null);

does not compile either. Would have to use null forgiving operator.

Comment: Hmm, works for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7UN8sJ (Net 7) https://dotnetfiddle.net/nEYCDH (Net 8)

Comment: Ahhhh, but I get a warning. Do you have "Treat Warnings as Errors" set? I can make it go away like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/04rS9K if that's acceptable to you ...

Comment: Or maybe like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCQ7RI

Comment: Yes, I have treat warnings as errors. So you are correct, I can disable the warning for instance with `#pragma warning disable CS8620`. I can use null forgiving operator too if I use `.When(foo => foo.Bar != null)`

So there are some cheap options here. I was however hoping to avoid them :-)

Comment: The author of FluentValidation has adressed this here, so it seems he cannot find a solution for this. 
https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1320